# How to get the least amount of transfers to get $4L$?

Tags: optimization, recreational-mathematics, word-problem

The problem is as follows:

> There is a bucket, fully filled, with 8 liters of water and two 5 and
> 3 liter empty jugs. All three containers have no markings that allow
> measurements and they are not of a regular shape. Using the bucket and
> two jugs and without spilling the water at any time, how many
> transfers must be done, at a minimum, to make the bucket and one of
> the jars contain 4 liters of water, each?

The given alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{7 transfers}\\
2.&\textrm{6 transfers}\\
3.&\textrm{9 transfers}\\
4.&\textrm{8 transfers}\\
\end{array}$

I'm confused exactly how to approach this problem?. So far what I have been able to get was only 2L in one of the vessels while the others have 3L and 3L

Assuming I begin as follows:

The first row represents the labels of each container:

8L 5L 3L

8L 0L 0L

3L 5L 0L

3L 2L 3L

That's where I end, with just 2L in one of the containers.

But that's it. I'm stuck. Can this puzzle be solved from here?. The problem only mentions three of these containers. But upon trying on different ways I can't get the right number of transfers. Can someone guide me on here on a method or way to get the requested 4L?.

It would help me a lot an answer which could include a step by step approach on how to get this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to solving it! I solved it in 5 additional steps continuing from where you left off.

As a hint, if you can get either 7/8L in the first jug or 2/3L in the third jug, then you will have a solution by filling the second jug to 5/5L and then transferring 1L to either the first or third jug.

Discussion of the generalized version of this problem found here: [Measuring water puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562855/measuring-water-puzzle/562864)

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't noticed at first but it was obvious. I'm ending with 9 transfers. By going with the 2/3 jug route (although I couldn't find a way to get the 7/8 jug as you noted) Did you arrived to the same number? I'm accepting your answer, but I'd like that you could help me on how to get it with 7/8L in the first jug?.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure that 7/8 is possible, since I achieved 2/3 first. It was just my thought process.